# How to get direction towards camera from vertex? (in a vertex shader, glsl)

Tags: three.js, glsl, shader, vertex-shader

I have this code:

```
vec4 localPosition = vec4( position, 1.);
vec4 worldPosition = modelMatrix * localPosition;
vec3 look = normalize( vec3(cameraPosition) - vec3(worldPosition) );
vec3 transformed = vec3( position ) + look;
```

But for some reason, it just moves the vertex 1 unit towards the origin point in the scene (0,0,0).
I need it to move the vertex towards the camera(where you are viewing the scene from).

I can't seem to find clear information anywhere on how to accomplish this.

Comment: Are you sure that `cameraPosition` is set?

Comment: You're right, it wasn't being set! o_o

Answer (score 0):

It was a three.js issue.. Had to set the isShaderMaterial = true, in order to get the cameraPosition to update. o_o

```
        material.isShaderMaterial = true;       //We need to set this so that the cameraPosition uniform is updated in the shader
        material.onBeforeCompile = function ( shader ) {
            shader.vertexShader = shader.vertexShader.replace(
                '#include <begin_vertex>',
                [
                    'float myOffset = 0.0;',
                    'myOffset = (vColor.r + vColor.g + vColor.b) < 3.0 ? 0.01 : 0.0;',
                    'vec4 localPosition = vec4( position, 1.);',
                    'vec4 worldPosition = modelMatrix * localPosition;',
                    'vec3 look = myOffset * normalize( cameraPosition - vec3(worldPosition) );',
                    'vec3 transformed = vec3( position ) + look;'
                ].join( '\n' )
            );
            
            material.userData.shader = shader;

        };
```

Comment: Just a comment about your shader writing - might make it much easier if you use the back quote in order to "open" a block of free text, instead of using lines like this and "\n"s with join. Just a tip.  ```function myShader() { return ` ... ... ... `; }```

Answer (score 0):

if you have a view matrix, transform the vertex position to view coordinate and then you can do transformation according to the camera axis.

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.